# Changing IP on CentOS machine

Tags: networking, ip, centos7, hostname

I have a virtual machine (from Hetzner) under CentOS 7.2. If I type

```
hostname -I
```

I'll receive:

```
172.31.1.100
```

But really, the machine has another static IP address. Further, we denote its as `<IP>`. So, I modify my `/etc/hosts` file as following:

```
# IPv4
127.0.0.1 virtual-client.domain.org  virtual-client
<IP>  virtual-client.domain.org
#
# IPv6
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
...
```

Than I modified `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` by adding the following lines:

```
BOOTPROTO=static
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=5.9.102.237
```

Then I restart network service but IP wasn't changed. 
In addition, I worked out [this](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-setting-rhel7-centos-7-static-ip-configuration/) and [this](https://lecturesnippets.com/lesson/setting-a-static-ip-in-a-centos-7-minimal-installation/) instruction but it didn't help me to change IP (in some cases the even network service is hung).

So, how to change IP adress on CentOS machine?

UPD. Output of `ip addr`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:a2:01:ab:1b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.31.1.100/24 brd 172.31.1.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 77783sec preferred_lft 77783sec
    inet6 2a01:4f8:c17:3b87::2/64 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5054:a2ff:fe01:ab1b/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

As you can see, the IPv4 address of eth0 still incorrect.

Comment: `nmtui` is your friend

Comment: did you contact Hetzner

Comment: @VeLKerr Did you add `NM_CONTROLLED="no"` in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`?